# Как завершить state в vkbottle?

Tags: python, вконтакте

Код с канала fsoky с его видео по обучению vkbottle.

```
from vkbottle.bot import Bot, Message
from vkbottle_types import BaseStateGroup
from vkbottle import CtxStorage
from config import token

bot = Bot(token)
ctx = CtxStorage()


class RegData(BaseStateGroup):

    NAME = 0
    AGE = 1
    ABOUT = 2


@bot.on.message(lev="/reg")
async def reg_handler(message: Message):
    await bot.state_dispenser.set(message.peer_id, RegData.NAME)
    return "Введите ваше имя"


@bot.on.message(state=RegData.NAME)
async def name_handler(message: Message):
    ctx.set("name", message.text)
    await bot.state_dispenser.set(message.peer_id, RegData.AGE)
    return "Введите ваш возраст"


@bot.on.message(state=RegData.AGE)
async def age_handler(message: Message):
    ctx.set("age", message.text)
    await bot.state_dispenser.set(message.peer_id, RegData.ABOUT)
    return "Введите информацию о себе"


@bot.on.message(state=RegData.ABOUT)
async def about_handler(message: Message):
    name = ctx.get("name")
    age = ctx.get("age")
    about = message.text

    await message.answer(f"{name}\n{age}\n{about}")
    return "Регистрация прошла успешно"

bot.run_forever()
```

**Как можно завершить state после ввода последнего аргумента?**

Пример: я пишу /reg, ввожу все что меня поросит бот. После он пишет что регистрация прошла успешно и больше не отвечает на любые сообщения кроме /reg.

Как работает сейчас: я пишу /reg, ввожу все что меня поросит бот. После он пишет что регистрация прошла успешно и продолжает дальше принимать последний аргумент и каждый раз писать мне что регистрация прошла успешно.

Answer (score 0):

```
await bot.state_dispenser.delete(message.peer_id)
```

Удаляет запись о юзере. Взял из [документации](https://vkbottle.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/high-level/handling/state-dispenser/).